# Reactor Flux and asynchronous processing

Tags: project-reactor, reactor

I am trying to learn Reactor but I am having a lot of trouble with it. I wanted to do a very simple proof of concept where I simulate calling a slow down stream service 1 or more times.  If you use reactor and stream the response the caller doesn't have to wait for all the results.

So I created a very simple controller but it is not behaving like I expect.  When the delay is "inside" my flatMap (inside the method I call) the response is not returned until everything is complete.  But when I add a delay after the flatMap the data is streamed.

Why does this code result in a stream of JSON

```java
    @GetMapping(value = "/test", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE })
    Flux<HashMap<String, Object>> customerCards(@PathVariable String customerId) {
        Integer count = service.getCount(customerId);

        return Flux.range(1, count).
                flatMap(k -> service.doRestCall(k)).delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(5000));

    }
```

But this does not

```java
    @GetMapping(value = "/test2", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE })
    Flux<HashMap<String, Object>> customerCards(@PathVariable String customerId) {
        Integer count = service.getCount(customerId);

        return Flux.range(1, count).
                flatMap(k -> service.doRestCallWithDelay(k));

    }
```

It think I am missing something very basic of the reactor API.  On that note. can anyone point to a good book or tutorial on reactor?  I can't seem to find anything good to learn this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code inside the `flatMap` runs on the main thread (that is the thread the controller runs). As a result the whole process is blocked and the method doesnt return immediately. Have in mind that Reactor doesnt impose a particular threading model.

On the contrary, according to the documentation, in the `delayElements` method  `signals are delayed and continue on the parallel default Scheduler`. That means that the main thread is not blocked and returns immediately.

Here are two corresponding examples:

Blokcing code:

```
Flux.range(1, 500)
    .map(i -> {
            //blocking code
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " - Item : " + i);
            return i;
    })
   .subscribe();
    
    System.out.println("main completed");
```

Result:

```
main - Item : 1
main - Item : 2
main - Item : 3
...
main - Item : 500
main completed
```

Non-blocking code:

```
Flux.range(1, 500)
    .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
    .subscribe(i -> {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " - Item : " + i);
    });
    
System.out.println("main Completed");
    
//sleep main thread in order to be able to print the println of the flux
try {
    Thread.sleep(30000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Result:

```
main Completed
parallel-1 - Item : 1
parallel-2 - Item : 2
parallel-3 - Item : 3
parallel-4 - Item : 4
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the project reactor [reference guide](http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/snapshot/reference/#about-doc)
"delayElements" method only delay flux element by a given duration, see [javadoc for more details](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#delayElements-java.time.Duration-)
I think you should post details about  methods "service.doRestCallWithDelay(k)" and "service.doRestCall(k)" if you need more help.